# EventSourcing / CQRS Implementation with ASP.NET Core WebApi and Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing, asp.net-core

I was looking for an easy implementation of the Event Sourcing and CQRS Pattern in ASP.NET Core using Azure Cosmos DB as Event Store.

As I couldn't find anything appropriate I decided to write a solution using the mentioned technology stack on my own.

The ASP.NET Core Backend receives commands, creates events and writes it in the event store.
The Azure Function processes incoming events and calculates a materialized view containing an account with the current balance and status based on the events received.

I put the source code on GitHub: https://github.com/marxxxx/EventSourcingCqrsDemo

I would say, it's basically working but there is one thing I did not understand enough to get it right.

One of the domain rules is: You can only transfer as much money as it is available on your account.
I put this check in the domain object (Account). 
However, as the Domain Object is just used in the Azure Function to calculate the latest version of the Materialized View, an error would just be raised when processing the event.
The user of the Web Api, issuing the faulty transfer is not informed directly as part of the HTTP response.

So my questions would be:
- Is it common when using this kind of patterns to duplicate the domain rule check if I need instant execution of domain rules as part of the request?
- Is my understanding of commands vs events wrong? Did I use the domain object in the wrong place? Should I use it when handling the incoming request/command to generate the domain events?

Thank you very much for any feedback.

Comment: How is it that a `TransferMoney` event is raised when an `Account` doesn't have enough money? Events should be raised *in response* to changes of state.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Well, in my WebApi i receive commands. When i receive the "TransferMoney" command, currently i build the current version of my Source Account Domain Object and the current version of my Destination Account Domain Object. 
Then i build the event "BalanceDecreased" and pass it the DecreaseBalance-Method of the Source Account (which performs the check if enough balance is available and decreases the balance).

Comment: Then i do the opposite for the other account to increase the balance.
This feels wrong and this is also stated by your comment because actually to my understanding, the domain object should receive a command and react with events, right?

Comment: If i change it this way, provide a method called "TransferMoney" on the domain object, and perform the necessary checks inside the domain object i would have to inject a dependency on the event store in the domain object to build the domain objects themself and decide if there is enough balance. Is this correct or should the domain object just contain the rules without dependencys on infrastructure?

Comment: Another thing i find a bit confusing is, that if i create with a decrease of the balance on my account as part of the TransferMoney command. I would have to do basically the same as part of the processing of the BalanceDecreased-Event when rebuilding the domain object from the event store. Should this be this way? Thank you for your help and patience.

Comment: You are correct that your domain objects will either need to be injected with the ability to raise events or present an interface through which the events they raise can be inspected. Regarding injection, there are two camps here: You can either inject the `EventStore` into all of your entities or simply make the `EventStore` static. While the second option may not seem as *pure*, it can help simplify a system. In practice I find a static store to often be the most pragmatic. The other option is to have each entity store it's events locally and provide an interface...

Comment: ... for your infrastructure to retrieve them. I personally don't like this option. Lastly, as you have astutely pointed out, the paradigm of consuming commands that change state and raise events in response could result in some duplication if implemented naively. Often the pattern here is to only check invariants and raise events in your command-handling methods. By having each entity subscribe to it's own events you can centralize mutations in the event-handling methods in a way that allows the same code paths during construction and mutation.

Comment: Ok thank you for your feedback. I updated the code now to use the same handlers for the events also in the command handlers to reuse the implementation. In this simplified sample, the command handler now seems almost useless but maybe in a more complex example involving multiple aggregates it still has a right to exist.